# optimal way of using malloc and realloc for dynamic storing

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out what is the optimal way of using malloc and realloc for recieving unknown amount of characters from the user ,storing them, and printing them only by the end.

I've figured that calling realloc too many times wont be so smart.
so instead, I allocate a set amount of space each time,lets say
sizeof char*100
and by the end of file,i use realloc to fit the size of the whole thing precisely.

what do you think?is this a good way to go about?
would you go in a different path?

Please note,I have no intention of using linked lists,getchar(),putchar().
using malloc and realloc only is a must.

Comment: Yes, this is called memory pool, and generally it is a good idea.

Comment: Arguably, it can be better to double the size of your buffer instead of growing it by a set amount.

Comment: What are you optimizing, speed or memory use? If you allocate 100MB up front, you will hardly ever have to call `realloc` at all. Might be the fastest.

Comment: Are you receiving characters from the _user_ or a _file_?  Post alludes to one and then the other.  An optimal strategy may differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you realloc to fit the exact amount of data needed, then you are optimizing for memory consumption. This will likely give slower code because 1) you get extra realloc calls and 2) you might not allocate amounts that fit well with CPU alignment and data cache. Possibly this also causes heap segmentation issues because of the repeated reallocs, in which case it could actually waste memory.

It's hard to answer what's "best" generically, but the below method is fairly common, as it is a good compromise between reducing execution speed for realloc calls and lowering memory use:

You allocate a segment, then keep track of how much of this segment that is user data. It is a good idea to allocate `size_t mempool_size = n * _Alignof(int);` bytes and it is probably also wise to use a `n` which is divisible by 8.

Each time you run out of free memory in this segment, you realloc to `mempool_size*2` bytes. That way you keep doubling the available memory each time.

Comment: so basically increasing the memory size exponentially?, and as for "2) you might not allocate amounts that fit well with CPU alignment and data cache." can you give a simple example for this?

Comment: @naor.z - there's always a trade-off between memory usage and performance. Your current way is totally cpu non-friendly because `realloc` is an expensive operation and you have too many calls for it

Answer (score 0):

> I've figured that calling realloc too many times wont be so smart.

How have you figured it out? Because the only way to really know is to measure the performance.

Your strategy may need to differ based on how you are reading the data from the user. If you are using `getchar()` you probably don't want to use `realloc()` to increase the buffer size by one char each time you read a character. However, a good `realloc()` will be much less inefficient than you think even in these circumstances. The minimum block size that glibc will actually give you in response to a `malloc()` is, I think, 16 bytes. So going from 0 to 16 characters and reallocing each time doesn't involve any copying. Similarly for larger reallocations, a new block might not need to be allocated, it may be possible to make the existing block bigger. Don't forget that even at its slowest, `realloc()` will be faster than a person can type.

Most people don't go for that strategy. What can by typed can be piped so the argument that people don't type very fast doesn't necessarily work. Normally, you introduce the concept of capacity. You allocate a buffer with a certain capacity and when it gets full, you increase its capacity (with `realloc()`) by adding a new chunk of a certain size. The initial size and the reallocation size can be tuned in various ways. If you are reading user input, you might go for small values e.g. 256 bytes, if you are reading files off disk or across the network, you might go for larger values e.g. 4Kb or bigger.

The increment size doesn't even need to be constant, you could choose to double the size for each needed reallocation. This is the strategy used by some programming libraries. For example the Java implementation of a hash table uses it I believe and so possibly does the Cocoa implementation of an array.

It's impossible to know beforehand what the best strategy in any particular situation is. I would pick something that feels right and then, if the application has performance issues, I would do testing to tune it. Your code doesn't have to be the fastest possible, but only fast enough.

**However** one thing I absolutely would not do is overlay a home rolled memory algorithm over the top of the built in allocator. If you find yourself maintaining a list of blocks you are not using instead of freeing them, you are doing it wrong. This is what got OpenSSL into trouble.